# Examples for using process manager approach in fabric8

Tags: fabric8

I am looking for some examples for how to use the process manager approach in fabric8. I read that we can create a tarball of the application we want to deploy and mentions that we need init scripts for start/stop ( http://fabric8.io/#/site/book/doc/index.md?chapter=processManager_md ).

Will I then package the init script within the tarball (my.tar.gz/bin/launcher) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using microservices seems to be the way to do it. And there's docs for it here:

https://github.com/jstrachan/fabric8/blob/micro-service/docs/microServices.md